# Paragraph and box width in Firefox vs. IE and Chrome

Tags: firefox, css

My web page is set to be max-width 1260px. [Edit] I realized that this problem exists not only for my page but also for all pages in the net (or almost all, perhaps those which have fixed width or max-width set).

When it is viewed in major browsers under 100% zoom, the paragraph and main column occupy more space horizontally in Firefox than in Chrome and IE. But Inspectors in all browsers show it is 1260px. Screenshots below were taken on 1920px wide screen, it seems that Chrome and IE have correct proportions.

[image]

In FF, I have Options->Content->Advanced->Minimum font size set to None.

Why the difference in FF and is there a way to have the page proportionally the same width in FF as in other browsers?

[Edit2] I just noticed that window.innerWidth javascript property measured on my page on my 1920 wide screen returns 1920 in IE and Chrome but 1536 in FF. So FF "sees" only as many pixels wide.

Comment: This question is off-topic here, but I think it fits [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). You can flag it for moderator's attention and ask for migration (please don't repost manually). Anyway, we'll need a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The minimal, complete and verifiable example is needed when someone has problem with code. This problem is not about my code, because every other web page has exactly the same result. How to replicate: set your browser zoom to 100%, go to http://stackexchange.com and measure by eye the left and right margins. In FF they are much narrower than in Chrome or IE, why?

Comment: You haven't indicated that it's a global problem, your question starts with "my web page" and you've never said that other pages are affected too. You should include that in the question, that makes it completely on-topic here I think.

Answer (score 0):

on windows. Firefox uses the settings in the the display panel for the default font-size of the browser.

Control Panel > All Control Panel Items > Display

Set all text item values to 10.

Make sure the font-size settings in both browsers are equal.

In Firefox: 
about:preferences#content > advanced

In Chrome: chrome://settings/fonts

Also set the zoom-level to 100% in both browsers.

This did the trick for me and both browsers display the same content equally.